# Apply column names to legend in a function

Tags: r, plot

I'm writing a function that takes two variables -- ideally columns from the same data frame -- and plots them.  The plot will also include a legend using the names from the columns, and that's where I'm running into difficulty.

The code below is as close to the desired outcome as I can get.  I'm only interested in using base R.

```
plotpairs <- function(x,y){
  plot(x, type = "l", col = "red")
  lines(y, type = "l", col = "blue")
  legend(0,ylim_max, legend = paste0(x, y), lwd = c(5,5), col = c("red", "blue"), bty = "n")
}

plotpairs(df$F3, df$F4)
```

[image]

Comment: `xname <- deparse(substitute(x))` and the same for `y`. Then use these in the call to `legend/paste0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you supply a `data.frame` or `matrix` as argument, you can extract the column names using `colnames()`, else you have to use `deparse(substitute())`, or `match.call()` as I've used here.

```
set.seed(1)
F3 <- cumsum(runif(1e3, -2, 2))+runif(1e3)
F4 <- cumsum(rnorm(1e3))+rnorm(1e3, 0, 0.5)
df <- data.frame(F3, F4)

plotpairs <- function(x, y) {
    if (NCOL(x) > 1) {
        nam <- colnames(x)[1:2]
        y <- x[,2]
        x <- x[,1]
    } else {
        nam <- as.character(match.call()[c("x", "y")])
    }
    plot(x, type="l", col="red", ylim=range(c(x, y)))
    lines(y, type="l", col="blue")
    legend("topleft", legend=nam, lwd=c(5, 5), col=c("red", "blue"), bty="n")

}
plotpairs(F3, F4)
with(df, plotpairs(F3, F4)) # same
plotpairs(df)               # same
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This plots the indicated columns from the data frame given as first argument or if no names are given then it plots the first two columns. Note that we first plot both together using `type = "n"` to ensure that the plot gets set up large enough to accommodate both variables.  The example uses the builtin data frame `trees`.

```
plotpairs <- function(data, name1 = names(data)[1], name2 = names(data)[2]) {
  both <- c(data[[name1]], data[[name2]])
  plot(seq_along(both) / 2, both, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
  lines(data[[name1]], type = "l", col = "red")
  lines(data[[name2]], type = "l", col = "blue")
  legend("topleft", legend = c(name1, name2), lwd = 5, 
    col = c("red", "blue"), bty = "n")
}

plotpairs(trees, "Girth", "Volume")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the sizing of the plot to accommodate the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I also worked out an answer based on the comment @Rui Barradas that included regex. Since I'll be using inputs like "df$F3", I can count on the "$" symbol to be present, though this might limit the flexibility of the code.

```
plotpairs <- function(x,y){
xnam <- deparse(substitute(x))
ynam <- deparse(substitute(y))
xnam1 <- substring(xnam, regexpr("[$]", xnam)+1)
ynam1 <- substring(ynam, regexpr("[$]", ynam)+1)
plot(x, type = "l", col = "red")
lines(y, type = "l", col = "blue")
legend("topleft", legend = c(paste0(xnam1), paste0(ynam1)),lwd = c(5,5), col = c("red", "blue"), bty = "n")
}
```